# Create veracrypt traveler disk in Ubuntu

Tags: encryption, veracrypt

According to [this extract of the documentation of VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Portable%20Mode), it is possible to create a portable "Traveler Disk" in the application:

> Tools -> Traveler Disk Setup
>
> You can use this facility to prepare a
>   special traveler disk and launch VeraCrypt from there. Note that
>   VeraCrypt ‘traveler disk’ is not a VeraCrypt volume but an unencrypted
>   volume. A ‘traveler disk’ contains VeraCrypt executable files and
>   optionally the ‘autorun.inf’ script (see the section AutoRun
>   Configuration below). After you select Tools -> Traveler Disk Setup,
>   the Traveler Disk Setup dialog box should appear. Some of the
>   parameters that can be set within the dialog deserve further
>   explanation:

My problem is I can't seem to find **Tools** → **Traveler Disk Setup**.

[image]

Am I missing something? I want to be able to share files on this disk with people running MS Windows.

Comment: the howto you linked only mentions windows - and since the linux and windows versions of veracrypt differ - i guess this is not supported in the linux version.

Comment: @dh429 on the upper right corner, linux is mentioned (of course this might refer to the software). I would expect the tutorial to mention that this is not applicable to linux. Any alternative suggestion to replicate the behaviour without access to a windows machine, would also be acceptable.

Comment: Mentioned [here](http://superuser.com/a/616879/649415) in point #1, it says that Linux and OS X distributions don't have this option, but the apps are already portable. **EDIT**: There's also a statement from a developer of VeraCrypt [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/VeraCrypt/comments/3rl794/what_happened_to_the_traveler_disk_setup_option/cwxubxj/), explaining the issue.

Comment: this question does not have anything to do with ubuntu, i therefore raised a flag

Comment: @db429 The question is related to operating system compatibility issues for a program and is therefore potentially related to Ubuntu since the OP is using that as their OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mentioned in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/615481/how-to-create-a-cross-platform-traveler-disk-with-truecrypt/616879#616879)<sup>1</sup> in point #1, it says that Linux and MacOSX distributions don't have this option, but the apps are already portable:

> I've installed the portable versions to the USB and they work fine for all 3 OSes. I obtained the Windows version using the "traveler disk" option. For linux and MAC this option is not available, but the apps are already portable. I just had to copy the executables from /usr/bin in Linux and Applications in OSX. I've tested them on clean system where TrueCrypt wasn't installed.

There's also a statement from a developer of VeraCrypt [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/VeraCrypt/comments/3rl794/what_happened_to_the_traveler_disk_setup_option/cwxubxj/), explaining the issue in reference to MacOSX, but the same concept should apply here.

> The "Traveler Disk Setup" option is available only on Windows. For MacOSX, OSXFuse must be installed on the target machine and we can't load it dynamically as we do on Windows with VeraCrypt driver. That's why on MacOSX, there can't be any real travel mode and the best that can be done is copy VeraCrypt application to the USB disk.

With these two pieces of information, I can assume that this feature is not natively included in the VeraCrypt application for Linux, but there are ways to achieve the same result. Both posts basically say to just copy over the binaries/executables to the USB as they are already portable.

---

#### Notes

<sup>1</sup>I do recognize that this answer is in reference to *TrueCrypt* and not *VeraCrypt*, but the traveler/portable option is nearly identical and the same solution applies here.